# Short term stay in Ireland while employed by US company - work permit required?

Tags: working-visas, ireland, digital-nomads

I am a South African working remotely as a software engineer for a US company. My work can be done from anywhere in the world and so I plan on combining it with some travel. Ireland is an obvious candidate as [South Africans do not need a visa to enter Ireland](https://www.dfa.ie/travel/visas/visas-for-ireland/) for less than 90 days.

However all I see regarding work permits discusses employers in Ireland, not work for foreign companies. Does that mean that what I'm suggesting is completely illegal, or that no permit is required for a short period with foreign employer?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that no permit is required for a short period with foreign employer - you are still fulfilling your obligations and paying taxes through your current employer. You are simply travelling and logging in from a different location for your work.